# Is it good idea to use admin.database().ref().on('child_added') in cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm creating a general purpose queue on firebase cloud functions to run huge list of task. I was wondering if i can use `.on('child_added')` to get new task pushed to the queue.

Problem i was getting  is that my queue is breaking in a middle randomly after 10 mins or sometimes 15 mins.

```
admin.database().ref('firebase/queues/').on('child_added', async snap => {
    let data = snap.val();
    console.log(data);
       try {
           await queueService.start(data);
       } catch (e) {
           console.log(e.message);
       }
   snap.ref.remove();
});
```

Or shall i go back to use triggers?

```
functions.database.ref('firebase/queues/{queueId}').onCreate(event => {
    return firebaseQueueTrigger(event);
});
```

Comment: Using on() in Cloud Functions is almost never the right thing to do, because you don't have any control over how long a server instance is running, or how many server instances are running to handle your functions. An instance could start or stop at any time in response to the load on your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i think that's the reason why it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `child_added` in cloud functions if you just want to retrieve data from the database.

`onCreate()` is a database trigger, that is triggered whenever new data is added to the database.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

so when new data is added to the database, at the location provided `onCreate()` will trigger. Both can also be used in cloud functions

Comment: I tried both `on` and `onCreate`, but `on` was getting stopped randomly at some point.  I wanted to know if there is any time limit for on, similar to triggers, like 60 sec or something. Thank You.

Comment: `onCreate()` is only called when new data is added to the database. `on()` will keep retrieving data until it gets the data in this location `ref('firebase/queues/')`

Comment: Ya i got that but the problem was breakage. I don't understand why `on()` gets data for certain period of time and then it just stops without throwing any error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in using `child_added`, it is in keeping an active `on(...` in Cloud Functions. The `on(...` method attaches a listener, which stays attached until you call `off()`. This by nature conflicts with the ephemeral nature of Cloud Functions, which are meant to have a trigger-execute-exit flow. Typically if you need to read additional data from the database in your Cloud Function, you'll want to use `once(....` so that you can detect when the read is done.

But in your specific case: if you're creating a worker queue, then I'd expect all data to come in with `event.data` already. Your `functions.database.ref('firebase/queues/{queueId}').onCreate(event` is essentially the Cloud Functions equivalent of `firebase.database().ref('firebase/queues').on('child_added'`.

Comment: i actually meant `on` not 'child_added', sorry for the confusion. I tried using both 'on' and `onCreate` for my purpose but what happened with `on` is that its getting stopped randomly without throwing any error. I wanted to know if there is any time limit for `on`, similar to triggers, like 60 sec or something. Thank You.